Why does kitchen faucet have no water pressure?
We recently had a water main break in our yard which caused us to lose 3 gallons a minute. Water company had to shut off the water main until we arranged to have the water main break repaired. Following the successful repairs and having the water was restored, we were instructed to open every faucet on cold settings and run for 30 minutes so that the sediment from having the water shut off and repair would cause to occur. We done so and from the moment I turned all faucets on I noticed the kitchen faucet wasn't working properly as it did prior to the issue. It has very little pressure. Very minimal water is flowing out of it. Why would this be happening? How can I resolve this issue without needed to call another plumber?

remove the aerator

That sediment they told you about has to go somewhere, and that somewhere is out through your faucets. It would have been a better idea to only run outdoor faucets since those don't have aerators on them... so now the aerators on your indoor faucets are clogged up with sediment, with the kitchen affected the worst.

After the water was turned off for Kitchen work, then turned back on, water pressure was lower to our bathtub. A plumber that came by later found and cleared sediment. I suspect that is your problem here.

probably clogged valve, you might need to open it (disassemble) to clean it
also remove the aerator to clean it
possibly all the dirt in the pipe found its way to the kitchen faucet
if you need help with valve post a new question with picture

To be specific, there are 2 shutoffs under the sink that can clog, 1 or 2 valves in the faucet itself, plus the aerator that can be clogged. Start with the shutoffs.

I took all the aerators off of all the faucets and cleaned them using vinegar. I allowed the water to run for 30 minutes, and still a trickle.
